# auto answer to bash command request

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, autocomplete, scp

I can copy files with scp that way:

```
scp file pavel@host:~/
```

but I have to enter 2 passwords

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa':
pavel@host's password:
```

How can I put such command in crontab (enter passwords automatically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in a crontab if you follow these steps:

Problem message: `pavel@host's password:`

**Solution**: make sure that your public key was added to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote host, meaning make key based login at least working.

Problem message: `Enter passphrase for key '/home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa':`

**Solution**: replace the password from the private key

The latter action of course introduces a lack of security, but there is no way around if you want to fully automate this.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more information about first solution? How can I find and edit  authorized_keys file?

Comment: copy you public key, usually at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the remote host using `scp` or whatever. Like this: `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pavel@remote:/tmp/pavel.id_rsa.pub`.. Then connect to the remote using ssh and execute the following command: `cat /tmp/pavel.id_rsa.pub >> /home/pavel/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Logout and try to login again. The second message should disappear now.